# Wall Anchor for shower door slider

Tags: shower, tile, anchor

I am going to be installing a 3/8in glass frameless shower door system in my new project. I have the opportunity to screw into a stud on one side, but not the other.

I would have added a stud in the location before I had closed up the wall, but the plan was to install something different before this point.

So one side may have a stud, or I can install one. The other side just has the 1/2 cement board and tile on it. Is there an anchor out there that could hold this weight for me? I believe the weight of the track system and one sliding door is about 140lbs.

http://www.homedepot.com/p/Vigo-Elan-68-in-x-74-in-Frameless-Sliding-Shower-Door-in-Chrome-with-Clear-Glass-VG6041CHCL6874/205759376?keyword=VG6041CHCL6874

Comment: You also need to think about dynamic load. Moving pieces exert much more pressure than their static weight.

Comment: Correct, I am hoping to have an anchor on that one side that will be over kill for the application, and then a screw into a stud on the other side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a conventional toggle bolt is your best bet here (and hopefully 2). You need something that doesn't rely on threads grabbing cementboard material, and something that spreads the load a bit.

[image]

I'd also use some construction adhesive around the bolt once it's in place to help fill the gap and provide stability.

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking. I assume I will have to check out different variations of this type of anchor to see the weights it will hold. Right now there is probably about 7/8in (1/2 cement board + mortar + standard tile width) of material between the open cavity in the wall and tile wall, I am hoping this will be nice and strong. Spreading the weight of the load with a wide anchor sounds acceptable.

Comment: I am a fan of the strap type toggle anchors. They provide more actual surface area of the toggle against the inside surface, but without digging in to the material.  The bolt also can be removed and reinserted without losing the inner toggle.

Comment: That is one of the options I was looking at as well. I am having a hard time finding one that is larger than 1/4" though. Edit: I found some...but the ones I found have a pretty small span on the wings. http://www.amazon.com/Toggler-Snaptoggle-Toggle-Drywall-Molly/dp/B005C4YE4M

Comment: They come in 3/8" bolt size as well. The span once inserted is about 2 1/2 inches.